# Can i get Unique value of each fingerprint while using TouchID in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to get unique value of each fingerprint while using TouchID. I'm doing that in swift3.1. Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: Have you tried anything in code?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get any unique information about fingerprint while using touchID. Apple doesn't expose that details as of now.